# query many to many relationship with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table named CustomerGroup which has a Many-Many relationship with the table contact_List. A third table CustomerGroupContact has the primary keys of both tables.

Here's what the CustomerGroup table looks like:

```
public class CustomerGroup
{
    public CustomerGroup()
    {
        CustomerGroupContacts = new HashSet<CustomerGroupContact>();

    }

    [Key]
    public int Customer_Group_Code { get; set; }

    public int Customer_Code { get; set; }

    public string Customer_Group_Name { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<CustomerGroupContact> CustomerGroupContacts { get; set; }

}
```

Here's what Contact_List Model looks like:

```
public class Contact_List
{
    [Key]
    public int Contact_List_Code { get; set; }

    public int Customer_Code { get; set; }

    public string First_Name { get; set; }

    public string Last_Name { get; set; }

    public string Contact_No { get; set; }

}
```

I'm trying to join the 2 tables to create an object that will look like the model below:

```
    public class Contacts
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm struggling to use the right query statement that will join the table based on customer_code property.
I'd appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: I see you have a `[Key]` attribute on some property, are you using an ORM (like entity framework) ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gYkTmKyA. This is what I have so far but I know it's so blatantly wrong

Comment: @RemyGrandin Yes I'm using EF  with Code first model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this would work:

```
    var userContactList = (from custGroup in _db.CustomerGroup
                           join     cList in _db.Contact_List 
                           on custGroup.Customer_Code equals cList.Customer_Code
                           select new Contacts {
                                            FirstName = cList.First_Name,
                                            LastName = cList.Last_Name,
                                            ContactNo = cList.Contact_No, 
                                            GroupName = custGroup.Customer_Group_Name
                                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            List<CustomerGroup> groups = new List<CustomerGroup>();
            List<Contact_List> contact_list = new List<Contact_List>();

            List<Contacts> contacts = (from g in groups
                                       join c in contact_list on g.Customer_Code equals c.Customer_Code
                                       select new { groupName = g.Customer_Group_Name, c })
                                       .Select(x => new Contacts() {
                                           FirstName = x.c.First_Name,
                                           LastName = x.c.Last_Name,
                                           ContactNo = x.c.Contact_No,
                                           GroupName = x.groupName
                                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code just a bit. I don't understand this line "select new { groupName = g.Customer_Group_Name, c })"

Comment: It does exactly what is says it does.  A new object is created with groupName being the value from the CustomerGroup class the and 'c' being the Contact_List row(s) that has same Customer_Code.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
private IEnumerable<Contacts> JoinTables(IEnumerable<Contact_List> contactLists, IEnumerable<CustomerGroup> customerGroups)
{    
    return contactLists.Join(customerGroups, 
                             x => x.Customer_Code, 
                             y => y.Customer_Code, 
                             (x, y) => new Contacts()
                             {
                                ContactNo = x.Contact_No,
                                FirstName = x.First_Name,
                                LastName = x.Last_Name,
                                GroupName = y.Customer_Group_Name
                             });
}
```

Comment: what is x and y in the above context?

Comment: Those are [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). LINQ is all about lambdas in fact :) Here `x => x.Customer_Code` means we take the property `Customer_Code` as the joint key from the enumerable `contactLists` (where elements are of type `Contact_List`). Then `y => y.Customer_Code` means we also take the property `Customer_Code` as the joint key from the enumerable `customerGroups`  (where elements are of type `CustomerGroup`).